# Keep geometry column from table in PostgerSQL database when importing into QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table called "polygons" and a table called "parcels". In "polygons" is a column called "shapes" of type "geometry" containing all the coordinates of the polygons. However the relevant information is in "parcels". "parcels" and "polygons" are connected via the column "objectid" or "parcels_objectid".

Now, I want to create a new virtual layer that gives me the geometry with the attributes from "parcels". I tried to use the following SQL-Statement in the virtual layer widget.

```
select parcels.*
from polygons
join parcels on parcels_objectid = objectid 
limit 5
```

The attribute table of my virtual layer contains all the columns from "parcels" but no entries and no geometry.

Next I have tried the following:

```
select * from polygons limit 5
```

This creates a virtual layer with all the geometry. When I try the following:

```
select objectid from polygons limit 5
```

I can't see any geometries in QGIS anymore. I guess it's because I don't select the geometry column when creating a new virtual layer. So I try this:

```
select objectid, shape from polygons limit 5
```

but now I recieve the following error:

> no such column: shape

When I connect my QGIS with the database and drag the table "polygons" to my QGIS Layer table, my polygons appear. However the column "shapes" dissapears in my attribute table in QIGS.

Is there a way to keep that column in the attribute table in QGIS? If that's the case maybe my SQL statement from above works.

**By the way**: Using the DB-Management tool it works. With this tool I can set "shape" as my geometry column. Eventhough I found a solution it would be nice to know if that can be achieved with the tool "new virtual layer"

Comment: So I guess you really the the geometry column? Because the goemtry itself seems to be there, just its representation in the table is not there. But geoprocessing etc. would work even without that. Just to make sure that you really want to have the column as well and understood that this is not absolutely necessary to work with the data.

Comment: In my PostgreSQL database I have another table "parcels" with all the values that I'm actually interested in. So I'm trying to create a virtual layer with all the attributes from "parcels" and the geometry from "polygons". Somehow it's not working and initially I thought it's because I cannot import the vlaues from the "shapes" column. Now I realized there is probably another problem. Soooo maybe you are right and it is not absolutely necessary

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to post clarifications. It's not fair to those who would try to answer to force them to mine the comment trail for information.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but i think that qgis layers geometry column name is "geometry".

Comment: Unfortunately, the "put geometry in one table and join to the attributes" model is a proven GIS [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). I'd recommend you not design tables in this fashion in the future. Geometry is just another field type, and treating that column as anything else only causes difficulty.